# Twitter card image is not always displayed

Tags: reactjs, next.js, seo, metadata

I created my site using nextjs, and set all the meta data required for a page. Somehow the twitter image wont show up in twitter. Here are the meta tags

```
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
        <meta
          name="twitter:title"
          content="Site title"
        />
        <meta
          name="twitter:description"
          content="Site descripton"
        />
        <meta name="twitter:url" content="https://mysite.com.eu" />
        <meta
          name="twitter:image"
          content="https://mysite.com.eu/images/ogg.png"
        />
        <meta name="twitter:image:alt" content="My site image" />
```

I also set the og tags and they work fine, what could be the possible reason.

I saw some other posts on stackoverflow but no one has provided a proper solution and the reason behind the problem